# How heavy is Mate desktop environment?

Tags: desktop-environments, mate

Considering the same reasons as in [this previous question on Cinnamon](https://askubuntu.com/q/181370/47206), it would be interesting to know where does Mate DE stands in this context - between Unity and KDE on the one hand, and Xfce and LXDE on the other.

So, to clearify:

On a laptop **with 1GB of RAM there's a sensible yet tolerable difference between LXDE and Xfce**: **between these and Gnome and especially KDE and Unity, the difference is decisive**. I use in parallel Xfce and LXDE, and wander whether there's another usable DE for me on this computer: all are "usable" of course, but compared to LXDE/Xfce not all are acceptable.

---

This questions stands being closed: I guess you should close the other one too then.

---

As reediting was suggested in comment: to put it as non-subjectively as I can: is Mate heavier on resources than Xfce? Is it lighter than KDE?

Comment: After recently installing mate desktop (from the mate repos, not from the mint ones), I would say it is 'heavier' than xfce, but still feels lightweight on an old computer. This question does seem a bit subjective, however, and already has a number of close votes, so perhaps it might need to be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd place it between Gnome2 and KDE, but very very close to Gnome2.  This is based on a netbook, where performance differences are very apparent.