# Which version of Ubuntu should I install on an old PC?

Tags: installation, software-recommendation

I just inherited from my neighbors an old PC with Windows XP as the operating system would try to use it with ubuntu but I'm undecided on the version to install, the two versions that excite me the most are: Kubuntu and Lubuntu. What do you advise me to install? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the hardware specifications of the machine?

Comment: The answers here might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/181274

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider installing [XUbuntu](http://xubuntu.org/). It is an officialy supported derivative of Ubuntu, which sports [XFCE](http://xfce.org/) as its Graphical User Interface which is very nice and notoriously lightweight.

Speaking from experience (I use XFCE on my Debian Virtual Machine, which I use daily for various tasks), **XFCE** is very nice and you are going to have the full Ubuntu experience even if your computer lacks raw processing power to support Unity 3d.

Some screenshots of XUbuntu:

**Precise Pangolin 12.04 Desktop using XFCE:**

[image]

**Application menu:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can install one of the following Ubuntu derivative on your machine:

- [Lubuntu 12.04](http://lubuntu.net/)
- [Xubuntu 12.04](http://xubuntu.org/)
- [Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/) with [Unity 2D session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Lubuntu and Xubuntu are very light weight and suitable for Old PC, you can see their web site and compare their features, but i recommend you install Ubuntu 12.04 and use Unity 2D.