# Which version of ubuntu would run the best?

Tags: versions, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which version of Ubuntu can I install on these specs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181274/which-version-of-ubuntu-can-i-install-on-these-specs)

I have an old computer and I wanted to know which version of Ubuntu OS would run the best on it.

My conputer stats:
1.5gb ram
ATI radeon 9200(128mb)
AMD Sempron 2300+ (1.58GHz)
80gb HDD

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're not able to tell you what *version* of Ubuntu would run best, as you are the only one capable of trying it out (I have another machine, here). However, more useful would be what *flavour* of Ubuntu. This has been asked a lot here already, so I'm flagging your question as a possible duplicate: [Which version of Ubuntu can I install on these specs?](http://askubuntu.com/q/181274/88802) (different hardware in the question, but it's effectively the same question, with useful answers imo)

Comment: Moreover, your question misses out two vital other pieces of information. 1) What the purpose of the machine is: desktop? home server? media player pc? etc. 2) What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements This can help you I think :) Your PC can run the latest Ubuntu version !

Comment: Your answer points to a useful page on the Ubuntu wiki! However, it would be useful to include what the essential part is, because it appears you're answering another question. E.g. "The system requirements page on Ubuntu provides suggestions for older machines."

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would recommend always going with the latest version of Ubuntu as (in general) it's going to be the best optimised for the widest range of hardware, even older hardware.  That or the latest LTS (long term support) version if you'd rather not upgrade more than every 2 years.

The only exception would be if your hardware falls *significantly* below the recommended minimum stats for the latest release.  In which case, instead of installing an *older version* of Ubuntu, I'd recommend opting for a different distribution.

Ubuntu (and most Linux distributions) can run on a surprisingly low specced machine.  512MB RAM and a 20MB hard drive, for example, is absolutely fine (and I even run full graphical Ubuntu in VMs with these specs).

Your system is more than enough to support Ubuntu, and probably many future versions of Ubuntu too.

I wouldn't go installing an old version of Ubuntu specifically to better support old hardware.  If you pick a version that is no longer supported, you are leaving yourself vulnerable to known security vulnerabilities which are patched in later versions.