# Will Ubuntu work smoothly with these computer specifications?

Tags: system-installation

Mainly I want a Linux system for web developing.

My system has following specifications:

- Intel p4 2.66 GHz
- 500MB ram
- 160GB harddisk

I heard that with removing some features during installation, we can use Ubuntu smoothly.

So which kind of features should I remove to accomplish this?

Comment: What graphics card do you have, that's very important for running the unity desktop. Also I'm afraid Ubuntu isn't really good for old hardware since unity came out, try using Lubuntu or another variant.

Answer (score 1):

500 RAM is the issue here. Ubuntu by itself is not the problem, but the desktop environment Unity; so it is most advisable to use **Lubuntu** (which is the same Ubuntu, but with LXDE desktop).

At 1GB, I would use Xubuntu/Xfce, but, from my experience, Unity and KDE are fully comfortable only above that.

More on this [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/181304/47206)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the requirements of Ubuntu
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Your system meets the requirements, but in my experience it wont run smoothly - specialy the Unity Desktop will not.

Maybe you can try a Ubuntu derivate like Kubuntu or Lubuntu. These need less ressources to work properly and smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Unity desktop in Ubuntu will eat all your memory. To run anything will cost looooong swap times. If you can add the memory up to at least 2GB, then you can be fine. If you have low memory, you can help the performance by lower the swappines parameter (follow this question: [How do I configure swappiness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness)).

Better you choose Xubuntu or Lubuntu with such configuration or increase amount of memory if you want to install Ubuntu+Unity. Option for Ubuntu could be to use Gnome classic or XFCE sessions.

CPU is OK, it is not a hit of last years, but will run your system and some set of basic applications relatively smoothly.

HDD - Ubuntu will take some 5-20G from your HDD, depend on set of app and the rest is for your Documents etc.